# Redis-rb client queue

Tags: ruby, redis

I am going to use this client library: https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb

In the github page, it doesn't say anything about queues. Is this behaviour by default? When I add a key/value to red is, does it use a queue datastrucutre automatically?

Also, redis has this BLPOP and BRPOP which allow you to block until a new value appears in the queue. Is this available in redis-rb? If not, is there library I can use that support that?

Comment: What is it about queues?

Comment: Well, how do I use queues with redis-rb? I don't see like a pop/push function in the client library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely, redis-rb supports all that you're asking for. (BLPOP / BRPOP / LPUSH / LPOP).

> ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > REDIS.methods.sort
>
> => ["==", "===", "=~", "[]", "[]=", "**id**", "**is_a**", "**metaclass**", "**send**", "`", "acts_like?", "append", "as_json", "auth", "b64encode", "bgrewriteaof", "bgsave", "blank?", "blpop", "breakpoint", "brpop", "brpoplpush", "class", "class_eval", "client", "clone", "config", "copy_instance_variables_from", "dbsize", "debug", "debugger", "decode64", "decode_b", "decr", "decrby", "del", "discard", "display", "do_or_do_not", "dup", "duplicable?", "echo", "enable_warnings", "encode64", "enum_for", "eql?", "equal?", "exec", "exists", "expects", "expire", "expireat", "extend", "flushall", "flushdb", "freeze", "frozen?", "gem", "get", "getbit", "getrange", "getset", "hash", "hdel", "hexists", "hget", "hgetall", "hincrby", "hkeys", "hlen", "hmget", "hmset", "hset", "hsetnx", "html_safe?", "hvals", "id", "incr", "incrby", "info", "inspect", "instance_eval", "instance_exec", "instance_of?", "instance_values", "instance_variable_defined?", "instance_variable_get", "instance_variable_names", "instance_variable_set", "instance_variables", "is_a?", "is_haml?", "ivar", "keys", "kind_of?", "lastsave", "lindex", "linsert", "llen", "load", "load_dependency", "lpop", "lpush", "lpushx", "lrange", "lrem", "lset", "ltrim", "mapped_hmget", "mapped_hmset", "mapped_mget", "mapped_mset", "mapped_msetnx", "method", "method_exists?", "method_missing", "methods", "mget", "mocha", "mocha_inspect", "mon_enter", "mon_exit", "mon_synchronize", "mon_try_enter", "monitor", "move", "mset", "msetnx", "multi", "new_cond", "nil?", "object_id", "persist", "ping", "pipelined", "presence", "present?", "private_methods", "protected_methods", "psubscribe", "public_methods", "publish", "punsubscribe", "quit", "randomkey", "rename", "renamenx", "require", "require_association", "require_dependency", "require_library_or_gem", "require_or_load", "reset_mocha", "respond_to?", "returning", "rpop", "rpoplpush", "rpush", "rpushx", "sadd", "save", "scard", "sdiff", "sdiffstore", "select", "send", "set", "setbit", "setex", "setnx", "setrange", "shutdown", "silence_stderr", "silence_stream", "silence_warnings", "singleton_class", "singleton_methods", "sinter", "sinterstore", "sismember", "slaveof", "smembers", "smove", "sort", "spop", "srandmember", "srem", "strlen", "stubba_method", "stubba_object", "stubs", "subscribe", "subscribed?", "substr", "sunion", "sunionstore", "suppress", "suppress_warnings", "sync", "synchronize", "taguri", "taguri=", "taint", "tainted?", "tap", "to_a", "to_enum", "to_json", "to_matcher", "to_param", "to_query", "to_s", "to_yaml", "to_yaml_properties", "to_yaml_style", "try", "try_mon_enter", "ttl", "type", "unloadable", "unstub", "unsubscribe", "untaint", "unwatch", "watch", "with_options", "with_warnings", "without_reconnect", "zadd", "zcard", "zcount", "zincrby", "zinterstore", "zrange", "zrangebyscore", "zrank", "zrem", "zremrangebyrank", "zremrangebyscore", "zrevrange", "zrevrangebyscore", "zrevrank", "zscore", "zunionstore"]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the gem fully supports everything Redis has to offer.

Check for instance [the documentation on BLPOP](http://rubydoc.info/gems/redis/Redis#blpop-instance_method).

There's also [this example on working with lists](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/f18a789afccf415633c783ccb2353e7210f678cf/examples/list.rb).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using an array that gets encoded and parsed in JSON:

```
begin
  queue = JSON.parse( REDIS.get(:some_queue) )
  item = queue.shift
  REDIS.set(:some_queue,queue.to_json)
  Do::Work.new(item)
rescue #just in case it fails
  queue = JSON.parse( REDIS.get(:lots_queue) )
  queue.prepend(id)
  REDIS.set(:lots_queue,queue.to_json)
end
```

Comment: Yeah, you should really checkout Redis lists and the LPOP command so you can do this safe and atomically in Redis. Your current approach will break immediately if there's more than one client connected. Redis is so much more than a simple key-value store.